# Show that $(p \land q) \to (p \to q)$ is a tautology without using truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My working is as follows.

$$ \begin{aligned} (p \land q) \to (p \to q) &\equiv (p \land q) \to (\neg p \lor q)\\  & \equiv \neg(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor q) \\
&\equiv (\neg p \lor \neg q) \lor (\neg p \lor q) \end{aligned} $$

I stop until here because I think my working is wrong somewhere. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct so far.  The next step is $\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor q)$.

Comment: Owh sorry I typed the wrong title, I have edited it now, thank you for your help !